# Posição de um Objeto com um nome específico dentro de um Array

Tags: jquery, json, xml

boa tarde! Tudo bom?
Por gentileza, poderiam me ajudar a resolver o caso em JQuery/XML abaixo?

Faço uma requisição de um nome de cidade ex. '**Vila Velha - ES**' via JSON a um determinado XML, e ele me retorna  um array de cidades 'Vila Valério - ES', 'Vila Velha - ES' e 'Vila Pavão - ES'.
Não posso simplesmente dizer que é a cidade da posição X pois a posição poderá ser alterada nos casos de utilizar outro nome de cidade.

Como devo proceder para que o retorno seja exatamente o nome da cidade que eu quiser?

Desde já agradeço,

Abraço

Comment: Por favor, poste o código que você tem aí, assim fica mais fácil da comunidade te ajudar. :D

Comment: Você faz a requisição de um nome de uma cidade pra retornar um array de cidades? Que dados você envia na requisição da busca?

Comment: Poste seu código aqui, para ficar mais claro, por favor.